# Adding new WFE to SharePoint 2013 farm - Missing patches could find anywhere to install

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, patching, farm, upgrade-sharepoint

During adding new WFE to existing farm found a patch mismatch, which I couldn't find  MS download center to install.

Below is the missing patch information

> Security Update for Microsoft Project Server 2013 (KB2760236) 64-Bit Edition

[KB2760236](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2760236/ms14-022-description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2013)

Note I have already installed a CU for SharePoint SP1 which comes after above KB.

Can someone help me to understand what I am missing here? Is there any CU for fixing this missing KB?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the below cmdlet to update the installed patches/products

```
Get-SPProduct -Local
```

**For more details,** Please check

- [Product / Patch installation or server upgrade required](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/)
- [Patching SharePoint Farm Considerations.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

Comment: I have already patched new sever to current build version with CU-kb2880554, and also all language pack with SP1. This missing patches are mentioned under French and germen language packs with "Security Update for Microsoft Project Server 2013 (KB2760236) 64-Bit Edition". Should I install CU for project server?

Comment: If you have Project Server, you always use the _Project Server_ CUs, not SharePoint Server CUs.

Comment: I have a SharePoint  Sever, Somehow I find a missing patch described as "Security Update for Microsoft *Project Server 2013* (KB2760236) 64-Bit Edition". Isn't it a project server KB? Which CU I should install to override this one. Thank you for you attention on this, I really need some help understand this.

Comment: @chriz Project Server is a superset of SharePoint Server (which is a superset of SharePoint Foundation).  You only need to apply the Project Server CU to get all of SharePoint and SP Foundation updates.